# AdMob keeps app stuck in onPause

Tags: android, admob, interstitial

I'm using AdMob interstitials in my app.  If I follow this set of steps:

- Display an interstitial ad
- User clicks on the ad, redirecting outside of my app (to Google Play, for instance)
- User selects "back" button to return to the ad
- User clicks "x" button to close the ad

The user returns to my app with a black screen.  After some troubleshooting, I found that the last event that my app responds to is onPause; onResume is not being called subsequently.  As such, my app doesn't know to reload assets and resume the game.

As a workaround, I put the following code in onAdLeftApplication():

```
        @Override
        public void onAdLeftApplication() {
            super.onAdLeftApplication();
            s_activity.finish();
        }
```

This way if the user closes the ad immediately he just returns to the game, but if he decides to click on the ad, my game is closed and he has to relaunch - not pretty, but better than a freeze-hang.

Can anyone recommend a better way to handle this?  Is there something I should be doing differently in onAdLeftApplication to ensure that my code gets the onResume message after the ad is closed?  Is there some other event I should be listening for?

One footnote, I've added firebase to this app, not sure what exactly that means but it's supposed to do wonderful things and I don't see any extra instructions for how to respond to an admob interstitial in this case.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Try this it may helps you.

```
public void loadInterstitial() {
        // Instantiate an InterstitialAd object
        AdSettings.addTestDevice("350cf676a5848059b96313bdddc21a35");
        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this,"222591425151579_222592145151XXX");
        interstitialAd.loadAd();
        // Set listeners for the Interstitial Ad
        interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
                Log.v("OkHttp", ad.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
                Log.v("OkHttp", ad.toString());    
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
                Log.v("OkHttp", ad.toString() + "   " + adError.getErrorCode() + "   " + adError.getErrorMessage());
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
                Log.v("OkHttp", ad.toString());
                showInterstitial();
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
                Log.v("OkHttp", ad.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
                Log.v("OkHttp", ad.toString());
            }
        });
    }

    public void showInterstitial() {
        interstitialAd.show();
    }
```

Now After Clicking on dismiss or AdLoaded perform the code which you want to do next for continuing the game in this you will get the listener for all the events and you can able to put different situation for the each events.